# How do I align these pictures vertically?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm creating a footer, and I would like to align the images of social networks vertically and **automatically**. As it has an increase in the size of the source of the contacts, the images are up. And I do not know how to proceed.

My code on jsfiddle: [Demo Code](https://jsfiddle.net/60c20whh/)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Teste</title>

<body>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="footer-right">
        <p><b>(43)3333-3333</b></p>
        <p>contact@contact.com</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-left">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/RVvPQt9.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/LsqUBIh.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/8PhKmDe.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/hDSPEMm.png" alt="Linkedin"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  padding: 0 4% 0 4%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer {
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.42);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer .footer-right {
  float: right;
}

.footer .footer-right {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
}

.footer .content .footer-left {
  float: left;
}

.footer .content .footer-left > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer > .content > .footer-left > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}

.footer > .content > .footer-left > ul > li > a > img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}


/*MEDIA QUERIES*/

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .footer > .content > .footer-right,
  .footer-left {
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer > .content > .footer-right {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, I want to align the icons vertically

Comment: in my solution i added more to the "source of the contacts" so i would have something to align to vertically.

Comment: As good as it expects, very good work.

Comment: And sorry for my English;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use table display css - the table-cell causes the floating to work and the table-header-group and table-footer-group cause the reordering.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    padding: 0 4% 0 4%;
    min-width:92%;
    display:table;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer {
    background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.42);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer .footer-right {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
}

.footer .footer-right {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: right;
    width:50%;
}

.footer .content .footer-left {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.footer .content .footer-left > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer > .content > .footer-left > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
}

.footer > .content > .footer-left > ul > li > a > img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}


/*MEDIA QUERIES*/

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .footer > .content > .footer-left {
        display:table-footer-group;
        width:100%;
        float:none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .footer > .content > .footer-right {
        display:table-header-group;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }
    .footer > .content > .footer-right p {
        width:100%;
        display:block;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>Teste</title>
<body>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="footer-left">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/RVvPQt9.png"
                                alt="Twitter"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/LsqUBIh.png"
                                alt="Facebook"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/8PhKmDe.png"
                                alt="Instagram"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/hDSPEMm.png"
                                alt="Linkedin"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-right">
                <p><b>(43)3333-3333</b></p>
                <p>contact@contact.coma</p>
                <p><b>(43)3333-3333</b></p>
                <p>contact@contact.coma</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Great, that's what I needed, good work, my friend, and sorry for my translator's English;)

Comment: jsfiddle is just a language that anyone can speak, i reckon ;) i didn't struggle with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code 
Here is a simple way for align vertical

If you want to add vertical middle box you can use below style for parent div.

```
"display:table;"
```

and add below property for child

```
 "display:table-cell"
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 4% 0 4%;
    display: table;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer {
    background-color: rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.42);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer .footer-right {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
}

.footer .footer-right {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: right;
}

.footer .content .footer-left {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:left;
}

.footer .content .footer-left > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer > .content > .footer-left > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
}

.footer > .content > .footer-left > ul > li > a > img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}


/*MEDIA QUERIES*/

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .footer > .content > .footer-right, .footer-left {
        float: none !important;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .footer > .content > .footer-right {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>Teste</title>
<body>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="content">

            <div class="footer-left">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/RVvPQt9.png"
                                alt="Twitter"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/LsqUBIh.png"
                                alt="Facebook"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/8PhKmDe.png"
                                alt="Instagram"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://imgur.com/hDSPEMm.png"
                                alt="Linkedin"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="footer-right">
                <p><b>(43)3333-3333</b></p>

                <p><b>(43)3333-3333</b></p>
                <p>contact@contact.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sonymathew/944behrp/)